# Elastic Search missing some documents while creating index from another index

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have created one index in elastic search name as `documents_local` and load data from Oracle Database via logstash. This index containing following values.

```
"FilePath" : "Path of the file",
"FileName" : "filename.pdf",
"Language" : "Language_name"
```

Then, i want to index those file contents also, so i have created one more index in elastic search named as `document_attachment` and using the following Java code, i fetched `FilePath` & `FileName` from the index `documents_local` with the help of the `filepath` i retrived file will is available in my local drive and i have index those file contents using ingest-attachment plugin processor.

Please find my java code below, where am indexing the files.

```
private final static String INDEX = "documents_local";  //Documents Table with file Path - Source Index
private final static String ATTACHMENT = "document_attachment"; // Documents with Attachment...  -- Destination Index
private final static String TYPE = "doc";


public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


    RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = null;
    Document doc=new Document();

    try {
        restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


    //Fetching Id, FilePath & FileName from Document Index. 
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
    searchRequest.types(TYPE);
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
    searchSourceBuilder.size(3000);
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
    try {
         searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }

    SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
    long totalHits=searchResponse.getHits().totalHits;

    int line=1;
    String docpath = null;

    Map<String, Object> jsonMap ;
    for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {

        String encodedfile = null;
        File file=null;

        Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();
        doc.setId((int) sourceAsMap.get("id"));
        doc.setLanguage(sourceAsMap.get("language"));
        doc.setFilename(sourceAsMap.get("filename").toString());
        doc.setPath(sourceAsMap.get("path").toString());

        String filepath=doc.getPath().concat(doc.getFilename());

        System.out.println("Line Number--> "+line+++"ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filepath);

        file = new File(filepath);
        if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
                encodedfile = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
        jsonMap.put("id", doc.getId());
        jsonMap.put("language", doc.getLanguage());
        jsonMap.put("filename", doc.getFilename());
        jsonMap.put("path", doc.getPath());
        jsonMap.put("fileContent", encodedfile);

        String id=Long.toString(doc.getId());

        IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(ATTACHMENT, "doc", id )
                .source(jsonMap)
                .setPipeline(ATTACHMENT);


        try {
            IndexResponse response = restHighLevelClient.index(request);
        } catch(ElasticsearchException e) {
            if (e.status() == RestStatus.CONFLICT) {
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Indexing done...");
}
```

Please find my mappings details for `ingest attachment plugin`( i did mappping first and then executing this java code ).

```
    PUT _ingest/pipeline/document_attachment
    {
      "description" : "Extract attachment information",
      "processors" : [
        {
          "attachment" : {
            "field" : "fileContent"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

But while doing this process, Am missing some of the doucments,

My source index is `documents_local` which is having `2910` documents.
Am fetching all the `118` documents and attaching my PDF  ( after converting to base64) and writting in another index `document_attachment`

But `document_attachment` index having only `118` it should be `2910`. some of the doucments are missing. Also, for indexing its taking very long time.

Am not sure, how the documents are missing in second index ( `document_attachment` ) and is there any other way to improvise this process ?

Can we include Thread mechanism here. Because, i future i have to index more than 100k pdf, in this same way.

Comment: What is the elastic version?

Comment: @AndrePiantino Am using elasticsearch 6.2.3 version

Comment: @Val -  I have attached my `ingest attachment plugin` mappings details. I did my mapping first for my index `document_attachment`. Then am executing this java code.

Comment: And you don't see any stack traces when running your code? any errors in the ES logs?

Comment: Some of the files is not available in the directory. so i make a code like, if the files is not available in the path, then ignore the `fileContent` ( keep it as null ) and index the rest of the content. This is what i planned and my approach also. But it is not happening in this way..

Comment: more over, i have a doubt that, is this approach is advice able. Am not expert in ES, but have knowledge in java not like a architect.